# Runtime whitelist APIM IP on function App using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

We are provisioning APIM service first(apim.json), Post which we provision multiple function App.
All the ARM templates are separate with their respective parameter file. We are using Azure Pipelines for CI/CD.

- Pipeline1   functionapp1.json
- Pipeline2   functionapp2.json
- Pipeline3   functionapp3.json
- Pipeline4   apim.json

We have an requirement of applying [Access restriction](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/whitelisting-azure-functions-mike-douglas/) on Function Apps. We want to add [Access Restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) using ARM templates.

How can we get VIP of APIM on run time so that we can white list VIP of APIM in access restriction section of Function app. All the pipeline are separate for each function app and APIM

Using API and get the value on runtime(Powershell) is one of the option. But we want to handle it using ARM templates.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the following to whitelist at runtime.
`"ipAddress": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName')),'2019-01-01').publicIPAddresses[0], '/32')]"`

Answer (score 0):

See "reference" function for ARM templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference

Comment: Just want to confirm, Does this reference work if the templates are deploying separately.
We deploy APIM.json template then deploy functionapp.json tempalte(Both are different pipeline).
Can this be used to get the value of APIM VIP in Functionapp.json tempalte.

Comment: As far as I understand - yes.

Comment: This worked for me.   
`"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName')),'2019-01-01').publicIPAddresses[0]]"`